# Wordpress multisite setup redirect too many times

Tags: php, wordpress, cloudflare

I was trying to connect domain to multisite wordpress. I have hosted in AWS Ec2 Instance and DNS is in cloudflare. Setup everything is done. But site is giving an error redirect too many times. Could anyone let me know. What was the issue.

Blow is my wp-config and .htaccess Code

```
define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);

define( 'MULTISITE', true );
define( 'SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true );
define( 'DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'domain.xyz' );
define( 'PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/' );
define( 'SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1 );
define( 'BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1 );
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
```

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I want to setup the main domain as default and want to create a subdomain for sites.

Comment: Is this your right domain: domain.xyz?   and are you able to login to admin panel?

Comment: Am not able to log in. It's giving an error. Too many redirects.